# Python DBF module is adding extra rows to a table export

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dbf

I am doing a bulk import of dbf files to sqlite. I wrote a simple script in python using the dbf module at http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/. It works fine and as expected except for a small few cases. In a very discreet numbr of cases the module seems to have added a few erroneous records to the table it was reading.

I know this sounds crazy right but it really seems to be the case. I have exported the dbase file in question to csv using open office and imported it directly to sqlite using .import and the 3 extra records are not there.

But if I iterate through the file using python and the dbfpy module the 3 extra records are added.

I am wondering is it possible that these three records were flagged as deleted in the dbf file and while invisible to open office are being picked up by the dbf module. I could be way off in this possibility but I am really scratching my head on this one.

Any help is appreciated.

What follows is a sample of my method for reading the dbf file. I have removed the loop and used one single case instead.

```
conn = lite.connect('../data/my_dbf.db3')
#used to get rid of the 8 byte string error from sqlite3
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor()
rows_list = []
db = dbf.Dbf("../data/test.dbf")         
for rec in db:
    ***if not rec.deleted:***
          row_tuple = (rec["name"], rec["address"], rec["age"])
          rows_list.append(row_tuple)

print file_name + " processed"
db.close()
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO exported_data VALUES(?, ?, ?)", rows_list)

#pprint.pprint(rows_list)
conn.commit()
```

**Solution**
Ok after about another half hour of testing before lunch I discovered that my possible hypothesis was in fact correct some files had not been packed and as such had records which had been flagged for deleted still remaining in them. They should not have been in an unpacked state after export so this caused more confusion.
I manually packed one file and tested it and it immediately returned the proper results.

A big thanks for the help on this. I had added in the solution given below to ignore the deleted records. I had searched and searched for this method(deleted) in this module but could not find an api doc for it, I even looked in the code but in the fog of it all it must have slipped by. Thanks a million for the solution and help guys.

Comment: Alternatively, a bug in Open Office prevents those rows from being read, or they cannot be encoded properly to the CSV file, or they are not being read properly from the CSV by the sqlite .import statement.

Comment: True also a possiblity but I have also viewed the file in xBaseView Dbf Viewer and other software and the other rows are not there. Its very strange to me. It seems the module must not be reading the file correctly. I tried the more recent dbf 0.94.005 module for python by Ethan Furlong but it would not work for me it kept throwing error after error and would not even open the file.

Comment: If you have the possibility of running the script on MS Windows and an ODBC driver exists for the particular DBF dialect you are using (_Visual FoxPro_ for example comes to mind) I would suggest using [pyodbc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc) would probably be the more robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wont to discard records marked as deleted, you can write:

```
for rec in db:
    if not rec.deleted:
        row_tuple = (rec["name"], rec["address"], rec["age"])
        rows_list.append(row_tuple)
```

Comment: thanks a million for this. I was looking everywhere for this method but could not find an api for it and missed it in the code files. I had begun to think that perhaps the module did not handle deleted flags. Thanks again.